# Financial - Calculate Yield To Maturity

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, financial

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173555/open-source-financial-library-specifically-yield-to-maturity) post about a .net library to calculate **Yield To Maturity**

But I'm wondering if there's anything like it for an PL/SQL approach?
I mean being able to call a function to calculate the YTM.
I searched everywhere and don't seem to find anything like it.

Ty

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Yield-to-Maturity and then implement the code in SQL.

Comment: like .NET, pl/sql can be used to code whatever logic you need.  So if it doesn't exist, then create it yourself